# How to find an html class name using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[html code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUi7W.jpg)

I wrote my code like this:

html_source = driver.page_source

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'lxml')
feed_root= soup.find('div', id="feed-root")
oneday_today = feed_root.find_all('div', class_="_1950o")
grades_today = feed_root.find_all('div', class_="_29Z79")

for oneday in oneday_today:
    print(oneday.text.split())
        for grades in grades_today:
            print(grades.text.split())
```

I want get result like this:

```
class_="_1950o" SOME_text
class_="_29Z79" SOME_text
class_="_29Z79" SOME_text
class_="_29Z79" SOME_text
class_="_1950o" SOME_text
class_="_29Z79" SOME_text
class_="_29Z79" SOME_text
class_="_29Z79" SOME_text
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Do you know what `for`-loops, especially nested, are for?

Answer (score 1):

You could get attributes with `soup['attribute']`, or in your case, `['class']`

This should work:

```
for oneday in oneday_today:
    print(oneday['class'], oneday.text.split())
for grades in grades_today:
    print(oneday['grades'], grades.text.split())
```

Comment: it matters what order first print TEXT class_="_1950o"  and then print TEXT class_="_29Z79" only. All another classes ignored.   At this moment I have this: TEXT class_="_1950o"TEXT class_="_1950o"TEXT class_="_1950o" Then class_="_29Z79"class_="_29Z79"class_="_29Z79"class_="_29Z79"  It`s wrong way .

Comment: @parataxis43parataxis43 then you should ask another question about the order or adjust the loop the fit you, but you asked about accessing the class name, and that is solved